# Using ngIf in angular but I am getting Bindings cannot contain assignments

Tags: angular

```
reservedcoders: ReservedCoders[];
export class ReservedCoders{
    constructor(
        public coderID:number
    ){ }
}
```

mycoder is an array

```
<td>
<div *ngIf="reservedcoders.find(s => s.coderID == mycoder.svUserID); else notEqual">
<button type="button" (click)="releasePopUp(mycoder.svUserID,mycoder.name)" class="btn btn-primary">Release</button>&nbsp;
<button type="button" (click)="addAdditionalPopUp(mycoder.svUserID,mycoder.name)" class="btn btn-primary">Add 10%</button>
</div>
<ng-template #notEqual>
<button type="button" (click)="releasePopUp(mycoder.svUserID,mycoder.name)" disabled class="btn btn-primary">Release</button>&nbsp;
<button type="button" (click)="addAdditionalPopUp(mycoder.svUserID,mycoder.name)" disabled class="btn btn-primary">Add 10%</button>
</ng-template>
</td>
```

Comment: what's with the `else notEqual` in the `ngIf` here?  `ngIf` already checks for `undefined`, it doesn't need an alternate state for the `find` code.....

Comment: You’re using an arrow function inside the `find` call; `s` is always assigned to the current item of the array `reservedcoders` as `find` loops through the items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is, but I have found in the past that somewhat complex expressions do often fail in *ngIf bindings.

The likely best solution is to modify your code to call a simple method in your component, and implement the "find" in that method.

So, for instance, implement this in your component:

```
public coderIdIsReserved(): boolean {
  return this.reservedcoders.find(s => s.coderID === mycoder.svUserID) ;
}
```

and change your template to:

```
<div *ngIf="coderIdIsReserved(); else notEqual">
```